# jQuery dialog show white content after multiple close/open

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following script :-

```
//--show add server dialog
    $('body').on("click", "#addserver", function () {

        //Make it a dialog box. Note that you don't have to do this every time the button is called, so you might want to make it dialog on document ready or something.

        $("#showserveroptions").dialog({
            title: "Add Exsisting Server",
            width: 600,
            height: 300
        });

        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Rack/showServers")',
            data: {
                rackid: "@Model.Rack.TMSRackID",

            },
            type: 'get',
            success: function (html) {
                $('#showserveroptions').html(html);
                $("#showserveroptions").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
            }
        });

     });
```

Which calls the following action method inside my asp.net mvc , To popular a dialog box:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Server")]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
        public PartialViewResult showServers(int rackid)//to display a view insdie the dialog box , for assigning servers to a rack 
        {
            AddServerToRack s = new AddServerToRack { rackID = rackid };
            return PartialView("_showServers", s);



        }
```

Currently the dialog will work fine , when first opening it, but after multiple close/open I will be a while content as follow;-
[image]

Can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: Check the `html` response; see if it is null

Comment: No it will not be null, and the call will be made , but the partial view fields will no be displayed . i check with firebug and i got 200 ok  as a response message..

Comment: Can you try to clear the html of the dialog before its rendered with partial view. i.e. **$('#showserveroptions').html("");**

Comment: @D_Learning i tried adding $('#showserveroptions').html(""); but it did not change any thing , and the problem is still happening ...